# Can I use @media queries and css classes in a Popup Window?

Tags: wordpress, popupwindow

I am setting up a Pop-up Window in a Wordpress 4.1 website located here:

http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/

You can see two options in the footer. The Get the Book link works correctly but the CSS is hardcoded inline and I can't change it for smaller screens by using a @media query.

Here the code I am using:

```
<div style="width: 48%; margin-right: 3.5%; float: left;">
<h3><span style="color: #fb6d03;"><strong>A practical guide to leadership virtually anyone can use.</strong></span></h3>
<span style="color: #000000;">A Journey of Epiphanies: Learning Leadership lays out the path –showing how our progress toward leadership affects us, the people around us, and our future. Then it applies these insights to help identify people that could become great leaders and helps them on their journey.</span>

<a href="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/a-journey-of-epiphanies-cover.png"><img class="alignnone wp-image-68 size-medium" src="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/a-journey-of-epiphanies-cover-207x300.png" alt="a-journey-of-epiphanies-cover" width="207" height="300" /></a>

</div>
<div style="width: 48%; margin-right: 0; float: left;">

<a href="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/amazon.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-70" src="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/amazon.png" alt="amazon" width="227" height="46" /></a><a class="buy-book-btn" title="Buy it on Amazon.com">Buy the book! ►</a>

<a href="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/button-itunes.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-72" src="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/button-itunes.png" alt="button-itunes" width="227" height="84" /></a><a class="buy-book-btn" title="Buy it on iTunens">Buy the book! ►</a>

<a href="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/bnlogo.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-71" src="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/bnlogo.png" alt="bnlogo" width="227" height="63" /></a><a class="buy-book-btn" title="Buy it on Barnes &amp; Noble.com">Buy the book! ►</a>

<a href="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/lulu.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-69" src="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/lulu.png" alt="lulu" width="227" height="80" /></a><a class="buy-book-btn" title="Buy it on Lulu.com">Buy the book! ►</a>
</div>
```

Basically **I want to dynamically split the popup window in half by using CSS to apply a @media query to it but the CSS rules I set up don't seem to affect it.**

You can see a live example in the "Download the First Chapter" link in the footer of the site.

Here is my HTML code using CSS classes:

```
<div class="one-half">
<h3><span style="color: #fb6d03;"><strong>A practical guide to leadership virtually anyone can use.</strong></span></h3>
<span style="color: #000000;">A Journey of Epiphanies: Learning Leadership lays out the path –showing how our progress toward leadership affects us, the people around us, and our future. Then it applies these insights to help identify people that could become great leaders and helps them on their journey.</span>

<a href="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/a-journey-of-epiphanies-cover.png"><img class="alignnone wp-image-68 size-medium" src="http://ajourneyofepiphanies.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/a-journey-of-epiphanies-cover-207x300.png" alt="a-journey-of-epiphanies-cover" width="207" height="300" /></a>

</div>

<div class="one-half last">

Form and Download link will go here but this needs to be the right hand column.

</div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
.one-half {width 48.5%; margin-right:3.5%; float:left;}
.last {margin:0 !important;}
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
     .one-half {width:100%;}
}
```

I have tried using plugins for responsive columns and more but nothing seems to affect the popup window.

**Any suggestions? Does CSS not work in the popup window? I am using the Popup Maker plugin.**

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a simple missing colon. I had

```
#body-wrap .popmake .one-half {
    width 48.5%; }
```

and needed

```
#body-wrap .popmake .one-half {
    width: 48.5%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an ID to the body element, then target that ID specifically ahead of the popu pop up in your CSS to apply to the contents of the popup. Then you would end up with something like this:

HTML

```
<body class="bunch of classes" id="body-wrap">
    Other markup...
    <div class="popmake" id="popmake"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#body-wrap .popmake .one-half {
    width 48.5%; 
    margin-right:3.5%; 
    float:left;
}
#body-wrap .popmake .last {
    margin:0 !important;
}
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    #body-wrap .popmake .one-half {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```